# how to print jagged array in text file

Tags: c#

I have a jagged array with size (array[1690][5]) which is filled during a for loop. I want to save the data in this array in a textfile as this text file makes from 1690 rows and 5 columns.
Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? Show us some code so we can guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just implement an using statement in order to close and save the file properly after using it and a streamwriter which is used to write on the text document with ease by simply using write and writeline methods.

```
using (StreamWriter st = new StreamWriter(filePath))
{
   for (int row = 0; row < arr.GetLength(0); row++)
   {
       for (int col = 0; col < arr.GetLength(1); col++)
       {
            st.Write(arr[row,col] + " ");
       }
       st.WriteLine();
   }
}
```

Comment: We should try to prevent answering unless they have shown effort. Otherwise we are doing their homework.

Comment: @Lynx thank you. may you explain more? for example, which command can use to write data in text file in windows form application.

Comment: From what I understood, you are asking me whether you use different commands in order to write on a text document in different applications, and the answer is that this way is used to write everywhere. It doesnt matter what your project type is.